# Big Query JSON Extract Function

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm  extracting 2 fields from a JSON using JSON_EXTRACT using BQ as the following:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('Event_Value','$.user_id') as cid, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('Event_Value','$.tsts') as ts
```

if the JSON format is missing one of the field I'm receiving NULLs all over the place.

Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Would you please add a screenshot of the table you want to parse with its sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I feel the fix is quite simple:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Event_Value,'$.user_id') as cid, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Event_Value,'$.tsts') as ts
```

So, there are extra `'` around `Event_Value` - thus `Event_Value` was treated not as a column name but rather as string